# Where can I find a good description on how to use COM with Windows Services?

Tags: windows, com, windows-services, interop, spwindowsservice

I'm looking to pass parameters into a Windows Service not only upon launch but while it's still running as well. I've heard the best way to do this would be through the COM but I have no idea where to even get started. Are there any good places you can recommend where I can find some helpful information about how to get started with the COM and Windows Services? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just get a piece of duct tape and magically "attach COM" to any Windows service. While it is true that you can host a COM object in COM+ and activate it in a Windows service process, but this is not just adding new functionality - it will change the behavior significantly.

In addition to [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548710/where-can-i-find-a-good-description-on-how-to-use-com-with-windows-services/2548971#2548971) you can use [RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378651(VS.85).aspx) - start RPC server in the service and make calls to it from the other process.